# SAS flag each row that contains the max value

Tags: sas, dataset, max

I tried searching but couldn't exactly find what I was looking for.  I have a dataset with multiple rows per ID.  I'd like to add a variable called maxdec and show a 1 for each row that has the max dec for each ID.

Sample Dataset:

```
ID    DEC
123   1
123   2
123   2
123   2
456   2
456   3
456   3
```

Desired Output:

```
ID    DEC  MAXDEC
123   1    .
123   2    1
123   2    1
123   2    1
456   2    .
456   2    .
456   3    1
```

Comment: What did you try?  It what way did it not do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to define it with 1 or 0 instead of 1 or missing.

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
  select id,dec, dec=max(dec) as maxdec
  from have
  group by id
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc sort data=have;
   by id;

proc summary data=have;
   class id;
   var dec;
   output out=max_info max=max_value;
run;

data want;
   merge have
         max_info (keep=id max_value)
         ;
   by id;
   if dec=max_value then maxdec=1;
run;
```

The proc summary calculates the maximum value of DEC for each ID, and outputs as variable MAX_VALUE in dataset MAX_INFO.  The subsequent data step assigns MAXDEC=1 if the current value of DEC is equal to MAX_VALUE for that ID.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a DoW loop approach

```
data have;
input ID DEC;
datalines;
123   1
123   2
123   2
123   2
456   2
456   3
456   3
;

data want(drop = m);
   do _N_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
      set have;
      by id;
      m = max(maxdex, dec);
   end;
   do _N_ = 1 to _N_;
      set have;
      maxdex = ifn(dec = m, 1, .);
      output;
   end;
run;
```